# How to minimize window using Ctypes in python

Tags: python, module, ctypes, minimize, maximize

like for maximize we can do like this

elif 'maximize' in query:

```
 speak('Ok sir!')

 user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')

 SW_MAXIMISE = 3

 hWnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()

 user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMISE)

 speak('done sir!')
```

Comment: in order to assist please give a minimal example that can be run

Comment: What? You need us to look up the value of SW_MINIMIZE for you?

Comment: 1st thing 1st: are you sure you typed everything correctly? Is it really *SW_MAXIMI**S**E*? What does the exception (error) say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set `.argtypes` and `.restype`.  `HWND` is defined as a pointer, and 64-bit systems will not pass or return the parameter properly as `ctypes` assumes `int` (32-bit) if you don't specify.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes as w

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
user32.GetForegroundWindow.argtypes = ()
user32.GetForegroundWindow.restype = w.HWND
user32.ShowWindow.argtypes = w.HWND,w.BOOL
user32.ShowWindow.restype = w.BOOL

# From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow
SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
SW_MINIMIZE = 6

hWnd = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE)
```